# Reverse Number Algorithm Bug

Tags: c, numbers, reverse

I'm trying to write a program to reverse a number.

Here's my code:

```
int num, rev, rem;
printf("Input a number: ");
scanf("%d", &num);
while (num != 0)
{
    rem = num % 10;
    num = (num - rem) / 10;
    rev = rev * 10 + rem;
}
printf("\n\nThe reverse number form is: %d.\n\n", rev);
getch();
```

Here's the problem:

Input a number: 123
The reverse form is 8321.

I don't know where the '8' comes from. Can someone help?

Comment: You didn't initialize `rev` to 0

Comment: Tip: compile with `-Wall` and heed warnings.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize `rev` to zero before use

Statement  `rev = rev * 10 + rem;` uses value of `rev` that is garbage.

`int rev =0 ;`

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want

> rev = **num** * 10 + rem;

Because as said before, rev isn't initialized..

Comment: That wouldn't work. Well, it would do *something* correctly, but not the same thing as what the OP wants.